# Bootstrap panel-group accordion with fixed position

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the panel-group to make an accordion as shown in the "Collapse" section of the Javascript nav at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse
Except that I want the accordion to follow the screen as the user scrolls down, so I wrapped it all in a bootstrap well and added position:fixed to the div's style. Unfortunately, once I scroll to the bottom and try to expand the accordion, it expands off the bottom of the screen. When the accordion isn't position fixed, however, the screen will grow to accommodate the new height of the accordion. Is there a way I can have my cake and eat it too?

```
<div class="well" style="position: fixed"> <!--Causes this div to grow off the screen-->
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a id="panelOneLabel" class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Title</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                <!--a bunch of content here-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--a bunch of other similar panel panel-defaults-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem by defining a height for the well and setting the overflow-y to auto in css. Now when it grows off the screen the well gets a scroll bar that allows me to get to any part of the accordion no matter what.

I just necro'd the code that I implemented when I was having this problem for anyone who wants it. The solution I went with at the time uses inline styling and probably isn't the greatest, or necessarily exactly what you want for your particular situation so I'd encourage anyone looking at this to think about their own choice of whether or not to use inline styling, and how to define their own css rules to solve the problem.

```
<div data-spy="affix" style="width: inherit; height: 100%; max-height: 80%; overflow-y: auto" class="well">...somewhere in here is my accordion...</div>
```